# AWS License type for Office if we use PIA in code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, office-interop, office-automation, pia

We used **Word, Excel, PPT PIAs** like **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** - *Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library* in our code to convert office file formats such as .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx to .pdf file format. As PIAs used, we understand office installation is required. Can run the code without office installation?? or only VSTO enough?

Our code is hosted on AWS cloud and what is the minimum license type like Attended without Power Automate or Un-Attended without Power Automate etc... that is required to install Office to make this functionality work (only this functionality required from MS Office).

Answer (score 0):

> As PIAs used, we understand office installation is required. Can run the code without office installation?? or only VSTO enough?

Yes, Office must be installed on the system to be able to use automation. VSTO is a framework for developing Office COM add-ins. They don't make any sense without Office installed on the system.

> Our code is hosted on AWS cloud

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

You may consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution instead.